# Angularjs: How to bind different result set with different controls using common method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and facing one problem.

The requirement is little bit unique in itself, Here is the description:

I have two inputs, two dropdown and two Get buttons and once i enter one url in first input field and click on Get button, it will bind all the "key" not values to dropdown using "getApiResults" method in the controller but when i add other url in the second input field and click on Get button it will fetch all the keys from second api and bind the dropdown BUT the problem is it also bind the first dropdown again with second api results because of the fact that we are updating the "fieldnames". I don't know how to handle this problem.

Please help.. Here is the complete code:

[image]

```
<html lang="en">
```

```
<div ng-controller="HelloController">
    <div>
        <input ng-model="url1" style="width:400px" />
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="getApiResults(url1)">
            Get
        </button>
        <select class="form-control" ng-init="getApiResults(url1)"
                data-ng-options="key as key for (key,value) in fieldnames[0]"
                ng-model="selected"></select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br/>
    <div>
        <input ng-model="url" style="width:400px" />
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="getApiResults(url)">
            Get
        </button>
        <select class="form-control" ng-init="getApiResults(url)"
                data-ng-options="key as key for (key,value) in fieldnames[0]"
                ng-model="selected1"></select>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
    .controller("HelloController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getApiResults = function (apiURL) {
            $scope.fieldnames = [];
            var serviceurl = apiURL;
            $http.get(serviceurl).success(function (data) {
                $scope.fieldnames = data;
            });

        };

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Please do not ask us do your homework

Answer (score 0):

They are both pointing to the same scope variable. You can make a small change to you `getApiResults` function:

```
$scope.getApiResults = function (dropdown, apiURL) {
        $scope.fieldnames = [];
        var serviceurl = apiURL;
        $http.get(serviceurl).success(function (data) {
            $scope.fieldnames[dropdown] = data;
        });
```

And then on the html:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="getApiResults('dropdown1',url1)">
        Get
    </button>
    <select class="form-control" ng-init="getApiResults('dropdown1',url1)"
            data-ng-options="key as key for (key,value) in fieldnames['dropdown1']"
            ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Comment: No this is not working because I was binding with keys of fieldnames[o] and dropdown values was binded with column names, With you changes dropdown is getting binded to thier values